# functions as objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

There is an object `c`.
It has a function `c.log(message)`

Is it possible to add some variables for using them like `c.log.debug = true`?

Comment: No, but I have some thoughts about prototypes of functions.

Comment: What are your thoughts and what do are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Just a simple console.log wrapper with options (silent mode, easy groups). Actually `c` is `$`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript is a full object-orientated language. That means that <del>almost</del> *everything* is an object - even functions :

```
var f = function(){};
alert(f instanceof Function);
// but this statement is also true
alert(f instanceof Object);

// so you could add/remove propreties on a function as on any other object : 
f.foo = 'bar';

// and you still can call f, because f is still a function
f();
```

Answer (score 2):

With little modification it is possible like this:

```
var o = {f: function() { console.log('f', this.f.prop1) }};

o.f.prop1 = 2;

o.f(); // f 2
o.f.prop1; // 2
```

Comment: This will break as soon as `o.f` is passed as a parameter(stored as variable etc...)

Comment: Yeah, but it's not. It's accessed from within a function that is a property of an object and the function itself has a property too.

Comment: I'm not critisizing, just pointing out what to be aware of ;)

Comment: Ok, I agree this isn't a good approach, shouldn't be used in robust code. But it still allows to use a condition in that function depending on the value of `o.f.prop1` which is a read/write property even from outside of `o`. So it is flexible and may be useful.

Answer (score 0):

It won't work like this. You could instead add the 'debug' flag as a parameter to your function, e.g.

```
c.log = function(message, debug) {
  if debug {
    // do debug stuff
  }
  else {
   // do other stuff
  }

}
```

Comment: Uhm, depending on what *exactly* the OP is trying to do, the answer is either yes, or no.

Comment: It's not a solution :) I think the better way will be `c.log()` + `c.logProperties`, but it's also not a solution.